# Sparsity of a sparse array without converting it to a regular one

Tags: sparse-arrays

My goal is to find such properties of a sparse matrix as the maximum/average number of non-zero elements per row.

The brute-force way of doing this is via converting the sparse array into a regular one:

```
MaxSpar[matr_] := Module[{curr, ms = 0},
   Do[
    curr = Length[Cases[matr[[k]], 0]];
    If[curr > ms, ms = curr];
    , {k, 1, Length[matr]}
    ];
   Return[ms];
   ];

MaxSpar[Normal[SomeSparseMatrix]]
```

How can we do the same without using `Normal[]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To obtain the number of nonzero entry of the row with fewest zeros:

```
Max[Length /@ SomeSparseMatrix["AdjacencyLists"]]
```

There are other useful strings. `"Methods"` shows which are availble:

```
SomeSparseMatrix["Methods"]
```

> {"AdjacencyLists", "Background", "ColumnIndices", "Density",
>   "MatrixColumns", "MethodInformation", "Methods", "NonzeroPositions",
>   "NonzeroValues", "PatternArray", "PatternValues", "Properties",
>   "RowPointers"}

Answer (score 3):

```
maxNonZero = Max[Length /@ #["MatrixColumns"]] &;
aveNonZero = Mean[Length /@ #["MatrixColumns"] ] &
SeedRandom[1]
sa = SparseArray[RandomInteger[3, {7, 10}]];
sa // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  3 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
>  3 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
>  2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
>  0 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 3 \\
>  0 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
>  1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
maxNonZero[sa]
```

> 9

```
N @ aveNonZero[sa]
```

> 6.285714285714

Answer (score 1):

```
m = 100000;
n = 2000000;
A = SparseArray[
   RandomInteger[{1, m}, {n, 2}] -> RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n],
   {m, m}, 0.
   ];
```

Maximum number of nonempty elements per row:

```
a = Max[Unitize[A].ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[A][[2]]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
b = Max[Length /@ A["AdjacencyLists"]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.122
>
> 0.053

A faster way (that works only for rows) is

```
c = Max[Differences[A["RowPointers"]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
a == b == c
```

> 0.000642
>
> True

Analogously, the mean of the numbers of nonempty elements per row can be obtain as follows:

```
Mean[N[Differences[A["RowPointers"]]]]
```